# Can't Add Child Block to product_list

Tags: layout, blocks, layout-update

I'm trying to add a block to the product listing:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_category_view translate="label">
        <reference name="product_list">
            <remove name="product_list_toolbar"/>
            <block type="core/template" name="helloworld" as="helloworld" template="helloworld.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="footer">
            <block type="core/template" name="helloworld" as="helloworld" template="helloworld.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>
</layout>
```

In *catalog/product/list.phtml* I have this:

```
<?php Zend_Debug::dump($this->getSortedChildren()); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('helloworld'); ?>
```

In *page/html/footer.phtml* I have this:

```
<?php Zend_Debug::dump($this->getSortedChildren()); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('helloworld'); ?>
```

Note that I only added `<remove name="product_list_toolbar"/>` so that I can test if my reference to `product_list` works correctly, by seeing if `product_list_toolbar` is removed from the sorted children list. **It is.**

So what I now have is identical code in the product list and the footer, and it only works in the footer. After doing some digging, I can't find *any* instance of a block being added to `product_list` other than `product_list_toolbar`. So, is there something about this block that makes adding children not work?

Comment: actually this is a good question and I dont understand why community is trying to close this question ! This is not surely an opinion based question. We should appreciate this type of questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is the order in which the blocks are specified in the layout XML.

`catalog_category_view` is technically the right handle, BUT in that handle the `product_list` block doesn't exist (yet!).

The `product_list` block only gets created in the `catalog_category_default` and `catalog_category_layered` handles. (And those handles are specified later in the XML than `catalog_category_view`.)

In short, when all the layout XML gets merged, your reference to `product_list` won't get executed, because it doesn't exist yet at that point.

The solution is to add your block in both `catalog_category_default` and `catalog_category_layered`, OR, create your own custom handle, add your block in that handle, and use the `<update>` directive to include your handle in `catalog_category_default` and `catalog_category_layered`.

Hope that worked for you.

Comment: Any page with `catalog_category_layered` also seems to have `catalog_category_default` so it seems that I only needed `catalog_category_default`. Other than that, this was spot on, and helped me understand *why* it was doing this. Thanks.

Comment: @TylerV. you are wrong on your comment. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed `catalog_category_view` is get processed for every category view page and you selected a layout handle correctly. However the problem here exists is that, we need to take care of the order in which layout handles are get processed in magento.

In this context, that is for category product list viewing page, layout handles are processed in this order (refering to [magento-1.9.1](/questions/tagged/magento-1.9.1))

```
  0 => 'default'
  1 =  'STORE_default' 
  2 => 'THEME_frontend_rwd_default'
  3 => 'catalog_category_view'
  4 => 'catalog_category_layered' 
  5 => 'CATEGORY_4'
  6 => 'customer_logged_out'
  7 => 'SHORTCUT_popup'
  8 => 'SHORTCUT_uk_popup' 
  9 => 'product_list'
```

This means when magento process `loadLayout` action, it will first consider `default` layout handle first and include blocks defined in this layout handle through layout update files. Then it will process `STORE_default` and so on. ***This means `catalog_category_view` layout handle is processing before `catalog_category_default` or `catalog_category_layered`.*** This is the important  point here to note.

Magento is defining `product_list` block inside the layout handle `catalog_category_default` and `catalog_category_layered`. Since `catalog_category_view` is processing just before these two layout handles, `product_list` block which is **referenced** in your definition is totally stranger and hence magento simply neglect the contents inside it.

### About your comment

I think you have misunderstood it. There are two types of categories based on layout. They are

1. default category
2. layered category

Magento will add different `layout update handle` for these two types of categories. For `default categories` it will process only `catalog_category_default`. For `layered cateogries`, magento process only `catalog_category_layered`. In both these cases magento will definitely process `action layout handle` `catalog_category_view` and `category specific layout handle` `CATEGORY_{ID}`. ie in short, `action layout handle` will get processed for every category view page. (category specific layout handle will be different for different categories.) See the proof here

File : `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php`

```
public function getLayoutUpdateHandle()
{
    $layout = 'catalog_category_';
    if ($this->getIsAnchor()) {
        $layout .= 'layered';
    }
    else {
        $layout .= 'default';
    }
    return $layout;
}
```

see `catalog_category_layered` will get included in layout update only when if category's `isAnchor` property is set to `yes` (we are doing this through admin side.). Otherwise it will process `catalog_category_default`

**In short** : *order in which layout handles are get processed in magento is the villain and hero in this case.*

Comment: You're correct about `catalog_category_layered` and `catalog_category_default` not appearing together. I saw `catalog_category_layered_nochildren` and got them mixed up. Oddly enough, `catalog_category_layered_nochildren` is added even on non-layered categories.

Comment: `catalog_category_layered_nochildren` is considered only when viewing category has no children categories. For categories that is holding some children categories, this specific layout handle will not get processed. Does that sound logical ?

Answer (score 0):

I put my reference and update under the handle `catalog_category_view` however the `product_list` block is defined under the handle `catalog_category_default`. It seems like this should cascade and still work, and I invite someone to tell me why it doesn't. But changing the handle used for this update fixed the issue.